# How to get a token for a POST request from Postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

The application is in Java.
application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9000
```

platform.properties

```
jwt.secret="......."
jwt.expiration.time=864000000
jwt.header.prefix=Bearer
jwt.header=my_token
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public Result login(@RequestBody LoginRequestDto user){
    return userService.login(user);
}
```

From Postman I'm trying to send a POST request to http://188.130.139.104:9000/login

On the Authorization tab, I select
Type: Basic Auth
[image]

I fill in the Username and Password fields
As a result , I get

```
Could not send request
```

Comment: Are you sure you can reach `181.121.132.101`?

Comment: I didn't understand. I fixed the ip

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're using oauth2 access token. To replicate that on postman you have two options. The two options adds Authorization to the header of your request.

**Option 1:**

On the Authorization tab, scroll to Bearer Token. Then put in your token in the 'Token' input field.

[image: via authorization tab]

**Option 2:**

You can add it to your headers directly via the Header tab

[image: via headers tab]

Comment: And where can I get this Token? How do I get it?

Comment: The token can be generated outside of Postman or from Postman itself. Depending in what OAuth2 mechanism you are testing, the relevant parameters need to be passed for generating the token.